# OS X Apache2 vhosts hosts domain not working

Tags: apache, vhosts, hosts

Setting up my local dev environment due to an update in OS X pushing new Apache Files.

This setup works fine when going to localhost or http://127.0.0.1 but when I setup the hosts file like so

```
127.0.0.1     bears.dev www.bears.dev
```

bears.dev just comes up with "This site can't be reached" in chrome.

Below is my vhosts configuration setup. I'm stumped as to why this isn't work, i'm pretty sure it worked previously.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName bears.dev    
       ServerAlias www.bears.dev
       DocumentRoot "/Users/Bears/Dev"
       ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bears.dev-error_log"
       CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bears.dev-error_log" common
       ServerAdmin superbear9000@gmail.com

       <Directory "/Users/Bears/Dev">
               Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In hosts file don't add two domains in line
right way is:

127.0.0.1     www.bears.dev
127.0.0.1     bears.dev